# gcc-11: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files compilation terminated

Tags: gcc, makefile, gcc11

When I am trying to run stylegan2 I get the following error:

```
NotFoundError: /home/chengjun/stylegan2-master/dnnlib/tflib/_cudacache/fused_bias_act_347e82e8919aeb0d5c7dc989e996c091.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder4AttrENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I use ldd command and find there is no link with tensorflow_framework.so.1

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdbe136000)
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/chengjun/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1ba7000000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/chengjun/anaconda3/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1ba72df000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1ba6c00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1ba73d5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1ba6f19000)
```

So I add the following path into the bashrc

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/
```

And then I run it again and get another error:

```
raise RuntimeError('NVCC returned an error. See below for full command line and output log:\n\n%s\n\n%s' % (cmd, output))
RuntimeError: NVCC returned an error. See below for full command line and output log:

nvcc "/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so" --compiler-options '-fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI= 0' --gpu-architecture=sm_86 --use_fast_math --disable-warnings --include-path "/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include" --include-path "/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/protobuf_archive/src" --include-path "/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/com_google_absl" --include-path "/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/eigen_archive" 2>&1 "/home/chengjun/stylegan2-master/dnnlib/tflib/ops/fused_bias_act.cu" --shared -o "/tmp/tmp8e0pgiod/fused_bias_act_tmp.so" --keep --keep-dir "/tmp/tmp8e0pgiod"

gcc-11: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files
compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it or what's the reason lead to this error? Now even I delete the path this error will not be fixed.

Comment: It looks like you built the program using a toolchain from an Anaconda environment.  In that case, you will probably need to have that same environment active in order to run the program.

Comment: I think I am following the requirements of the developers, except for the version of gcc, because I don't have the root to change. Do you think this will affect the environment or not?

Comment: Questions about which versions of gcc are suitable for compiling the software would be better directed to its developers.  My point was that if you use a GCC from an Anaconda envrionment then that likely ties the executable to that same Anaconda environment, even if it's not actually installed inside.